# Are questions about missiles and radars that shot planes down in history on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There are some examples where a country has shot a passenger plane down and justify it by "the radar can't distinguish between war jets and passenger planes".

Is it on-topic to ask about the country's claim that the radar is unable to distinguish between war jets and passenger planes?

If not, where can these questions be asked?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion such a question would be on topic if it focuses on the technical and operational aspects and steers away from the political aspects.